# Execute two query from mysql in same page by passing value in url

Tags: php, mysql, url, post, get

I have created a page in php
I want to show when user type in weektable.php it should show all the value i.e it should execute this query

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `battery`";
```

above query display all the value.

and when user type in url weektable.php?sort=w it should execute this query

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM battery WHERE date BETWEEN '".$week."' AND '" .$date."'";
```

above query display value between current date and one week before date.

But I have no Idea how to do it.
I want to do it without go to another page i.e I want show both the value in same page

Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'my_db';
$userdb = 'root';
$passdb = 'root';

try {

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8


$currDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date = $currDate ;
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp
$ts = strtotime($date);
// calculate the number of days since Monday
$dow = date('w', $ts);
//$offset = $dow - 3;
$offset = $dow - date('d');
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 6;
}
// calculate timestamp for the Monday
$ts = $ts - $offset*86400;
// loop from Monday till Sunday
for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++, $ts += 86400){
    //print date("Y-m-d l", $ts) ."</br>" . "\n";
$week = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ts) ."</br>";

}

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `battery`";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM battery WHERE date BETWEEN '".$week."' AND '" .$date."'";


  $result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1' style='font-family:arial;font-size12px;' cellspacing=1>
<tr>
<th>User Id</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>LastName</th>
<th>EmailId</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";

  while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['emailid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }

echo "</table>";

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Please I need help.
Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Define a different variable for second query. such as `$sql_range = "SELECT * FROM battery WHERE date BETWEEN '".$week."' AND '" .$date."'";` and then fetch results for it in a separate variable `$result2 = $conn->query($sql_range );`

I hope that should solve your question.

Comment: But for this I will have to write again new table in html. I don't want to create new table.

Comment: then where and how exactly are you planning to use both the fetched results??

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET["sort"])) {
  if ($_GET["sort"] == "w") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM battery WHERE date BETWEEN '".$week."' AND '" .$date."'";
  }
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `battery`";
}
```

I'm assuming that you are requesting this page with something like:

```
./weektable.php?sort=w
```

I was also a bit lazy and should have added as isset($_GET["sort"]) - I have edited the code sample above..... EDIT sorry become very rushed IRL, I hope this helps. Thanks to those that pointed out earlier error.

Comment: @AI.: But it does not work for me it shows me now error Notice: Undefined variable: GET in weektable.php on line 41

Comment: Now I correct error in get . but now it shows another error:Notice: Undefined index: sort in weektable.php on line 41